# How to iterate JSONArray in java

Tags: java, json, parsing, arrays

I would like to extract the values from JSONArray. JSONArray has N number of rows and columns.

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        DynamicForm dynamicForm = new DynamicForm();
        dynamicForm = dynamicForm.bindFromRequest();
        Dynamic dynamic = dynamicForm.get(); 
        //List<OneModel> list = new ArrayList<OneModel>();
        //List iterate=new ArrayList();

        String data = dynamic.getData().get("content").toString();
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println(jsonArray.get(i));
        } }catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Its resulting as follows.

```
["1001432","05-KALENJI-P1229","KALENJI","2","2014-11-09 09:37:14.379482",""],
["1001432","05-KALENJI-P1228","KALENJI","1","2014-11-09 09:37:14.379482",""],
["1001432","05-KALENJI-P1227","KALENJI","5","2014-11-09 09:37:14.379482",""]
```

I would like to extract one by one values and assign it to variable. for example 1001432,05-KALENJI-P1229,KALENJI,2,2014-11-09 09:37:14.379482. So that i can process each values. Please any one help me in the same

Comment: Please post the Json which you wanna to retrive

Comment: [["1001556","5-KIPSTA","KIPSTA","1","2014-11-09 15:12:44.713654"]}]

Comment: @KathirvelAppusamy That's not valid JSON. Please post the full value of the content key, i.e. the value of dynamic.getData().get("content").toString()

Comment: The following is the array which i am getting from the dynamic.getData().get("content").toString()  [["1001556","5-KIPSTA-P414","KIPSTA","1","2014-11-09 15:12:44.713654"],["1001556","5-KIPSTA-P412","KIPSTA","1","2014-11-09 15:12:44.713654"]]

Comment: Can you please let me know how to parse the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following code:

//put your json in the string variable "data"

```
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(data);
            if(jsonArray!=null && jsonArray.length()>0){
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONArray childJsonArray=jsonArray.optJSONArray(i);
                    if(childJsonArray!=null && childJsonArray.length()>0){
                        for (int j = 0; j < childJsonArray.length(); j++) {
                            System.out.println(childJsonArray.optString(j));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: It would be great if you can show me how to extract index by index(in the do your code here part)

Comment: Please share your full json, so i will extract it and share perfact code .

Comment: here is my complete jsonarray [["1001556","5-KIPSTA-P414","KIPSTA","1","2014-11-09 15:12:44.713654"],["1001556","5-KIPSTA-P412","KIPSTA","1","2014-11-09 15:12:44.713654"]]. Please help me

Comment: @KathirvelAppusamy Please check code, it's work fine, and please accept answer.

Comment: @KathirvelAppusamy then please accept this answer, so this will help other also.

Comment: @Krunal Indrodiya I think it's not a good behavior to fource the op to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the JSON array is 2 dimensional. Try this:

```
JSONArray outerArray = new JSONArray(data);
for (int i = 0; i < outerArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray innerArray = outerArray.getJSONArray(i);

    for (int j = 0; j < outerArray.length(); j++) {
        System.out.println(innerArray.get(j));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can iterate over the array via a loop and get your objects like this:

```
 JsonObject home = array.getJsonObject(index); //use index to iterate
 String num = home.getString("number"); //make number a static final variable
```

The "number" is the name for the value, which was originally put in with

```
.add("number", someString);
```

Greets.

edit:
I recommend to read the docu: [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) and [this, too.](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html)

Comment: There is no index called number. I can iterate through only index values such as 0,1,2,3 etc.. So Please give me some other solution. Its not working for me

Comment: If you don't know the label of the strings, then the optString method provided by some of the other answers should do the job, as well.